# Swift 3.1 UITextField Type 'String.Index' (aka 'String.CharacterView.Index') does not conform to protocol '_Strideable'

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

I had implemented a uitextfield delegate method `textFieldToChange` to allow only certain characters in the text field. Recently I updated my app to swift 3.1 and now I am getting a `Type 'String.Index' (aka 'String.CharacterView.Index') does not conform to protocol '_Strideable'` error. I am attatching a snapshot of my code:

[image]

Please help me get this issue resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem recently and the solution that worked for me was to check if non of the characters match the inverted set of my allowed characters rather than to check if all characters match the allowed characters set. Below piece of code worked perfectly for me.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet.letters
        if string.isEmpty {
            return true
        } else if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedCharacterSet.inverted) != nil {  //check if the input contains anything else than letters
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
```